# I am tryng to print out all longst strngs and what i have managed to do is just print the first 2 strings

Tags: javascript

```js
   

let printLongestStrings =(array) =>{
let longStr = "";
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i].length >= longStr.length){
      longStr += array[i];
  }
} 
return longStr;  
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time","ticking","bomb","countup"]));
```

Comment: 1) You're comparing a string's `.length` to a string… 2) You're concatenating to `longStr`, meaning it'll get longer and longer… 3) You're `return`ing on the first iteration, so it'll never try more than one…

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Early returning should be there. You should return `longStr` at last.

```
  return longStr;
```

**2)** You should compare `array[i].length` with `longStr.length` not with `longStr`

```
array[i].length >= longStr.length
```

**3)** You should assign the largest string to `longStr`. You shouldn't append it in `longStr`.

```
longStr = array[i].length >= longStr.length ? array[i] : longStr;
```

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  let longStr = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    longStr = array[i].length >= longStr.length ? array[i] : longStr;
  }
  return longStr;
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

---

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:** You can achieve the same result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr.length >= acc.length ? curr : acc));
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

**If you want array of largest length string**

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  let map = new Map(),
    largestLength = 0;

  array.forEach((s) => {
    if (s.length >= largestLength) {
      largestLength = s.length;
      map.has(s.length) ? map.get(s.length).push(s) : map.set(s.length, [s]);
    }
  });
  return [...map.get(largestLength)];
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

Comment: Shouldn't "ticking" be included in the output? It has the same length as "countup".

Comment: i get it but it only prints one longest string and there are two longest strings in the array.

Comment: But OP want to use `>=` for comparison

Comment: yea, it should be included because its of the same length with countup.

Comment: So @NATHANIEL You want array of same largest length strings. Is that right?

Comment: @NATHANIEL Now you will get an array of largest same length. Have a look

Comment: [I wrote some code too](https://jsfiddle.net/Logjqnm2/1/) which you might find interesting. @NATHANIEL.

Comment: I came up with same solution @Andy but I think It will take 2 round(loop) to get the result. But I want to achieve the result in one go that's why I've used `forEach` and `Map`

Comment: Though your solution is concise and easy to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: And I was also bored and needed something constructive to do :)

Comment: lol, thats quite dope. thank you @ HR01M8055 and @Andy.

Comment: hey, lets say i dont want it to output an array? just the strings?

Comment: then use `[...map.get(largestLength)].join(", ")` . Use the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: not to separate it by a comma but to print each string on a new line?

Comment: `return [...map.get(largestLength)].forEach((s) => console.log(s));` This would work

Comment: it does work but it seems it also added an undefined value.

Comment: That's because you are logging out the output of `printLongestStrings` function . Just remove the console.log and run as `printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]);`

Comment: awesome. :)  okay, do you think you can write the code without built in methods?

Comment: @NATHANIEL If you have another question then please ask again.   It is not advised to ask question inside another quesiton in a comment. Hope you understand

Comment: Alright cool. thank you again.

Comment: Would you mind If you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20vote%20up,arrow%20to%20undo%20a%20downvote.) and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning before you've checked all the strings

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  let longStr = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].length >= longStr.length)
      longStr = array[i];      
  }
  return longStr;
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

The above will print the last longest string (ie, if more than 1 input is the longest length it will just output the last)

If yo want *all* of the strings this length the below would work

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  let longLen = 0;
  let longStr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].length == longLen){
       longStr.push(array[i])
    }
    else if(array[i].length > longLen){
      longStr = [];
      longLen = array[i].length;
      longStr.push(array[i])
    }
  }
  return longStr;
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

Comment: i tried using that but it only prints the last string or just one long string, the ideal outcome is to print all longest strings.

Comment: @NATHANIEL see update

Comment: awesome :) thank you... any advice on how to improve my skill?

Comment: @NATHANIEL practice.

Comment: cool, thank you again... lets say i dont want it to output an array?

Comment: @NATHANIEL then what _do_ you want to output it as? You could always call `.join(",")` on the result to get a comma separated string

Comment: i want each string to print on a new line

Comment: @NATHANIEL `.join("\n")` or `.join("<br>")` (if HTML) then

Comment: okay awesome... quick question, after the else if statement, why is it neccessary to add longStr = []; again even after declaring it the first time?

Comment: @NATHANIEL you've found a longer string than previously found, so it is essentially clearing the array of "longest strings" by creating a new empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a couple of modifications to your code, and it will work :

1. You are not checking the length of the `longStr` when comparing.
2. You are returning from **the very first iteration**. Return at the end.
3. Assign the correct value, based on your comparison of lengths. The one whose `.length` is greater.

```js
let printLongestStrings = (array) => {
  let longStr = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    longStr = (array[i].length >= longStr.length) ? array[i] : longStr;
  }
  return longStr;
};
console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

Comment: okay but there are two strings ofthe same length but it only prints one?

Answer (score 0):

This gives `ticking`:

```
let printLongestStrings = array => {
  const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  let i = 0;
  const returned = [sorted[i]];
  while(sorted[i].length == sorted[i+1].length){
    returned.push(sorted[++i]);
  }
  return returned;
}

console.log(printLongestStrings(["time", "ticking", "bomb", "countup"]));
```

Comment: is it possible to print both ticking and countup because they are of the same length

Comment: @NATHANIEL I've edited the answer, check it out